# Bulk XML to JSON conversion

Tags: python, json, xml, parsing

Can anyone recommend some good XML to JSON conversion tools/scripts for converting over 1 million XML records?

Comment: xml2json.js is a js library for converting xml files to json format, you can craate a small program using this script, or try my online xml to json converter https://xmltojson.tk/ , you can convert multiple xml files in a single click,  created with xml2json.js

Answer (score 3):

One way to do this is to convert xml to dict and then dict to JSON . Here is a quick example

```
import json
import xmltodict

def convertXmlToJSON(xmlFile, xml_attribs=True):
    with open(xmlFile, "rb") as file:
        my_dict = xmltodict.parse(file, xml_attribs=xml_attribs)
        return json.dumps(my_dict, indent=4,separators=(',', ': '))
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need Python for this.

You should be able to use [XSLT](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/) to achieve this pretty easily.